# How to programmatically add post body (Body Data) with Jmeter API?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using the java Jmeter Api to create jmeter scripts from java. I am creating http requests with HTTPSamplerProxy and i need to add post body or "Body Data" as it called in the Jmeter GUI.

I need some help on how to add a json to the "Body Data".

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Answer (score 2):

i have found the answer to my problem:
HTTPSamplerProxy.addEncodedArgument("Body Data", "the post body data you want to use", "");

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue but if there already some arguments `addEncodedArgument` will be not the first one i.e. not the body.So I've tried this:

```
    if(((HTTPSamplerProxy)sampler).getArguments()==null){
        ((HTTPSamplerProxy)sampler).addNonEncodedArgument("body", body, "");
    }else{
        ((HTTPSamplerProxy)sampler).getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(body);
    }
```